# How to rewrite URL for a menu item in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, menuitem

I have a menu item that looks like this:

```
mysite.com/index.php?option=blog&view=index
```

and I want it to become like this:

```
blog.mysite.com
```

Can it be done?

Thank you!

Edit:

@Daan The rule gives me a 500 internal server error. I'm using joomla cms, the default htaccess looks like this

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]

RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /component/|(/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|vcf|raw))$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

my site is on a paid hosting server and i don't have access to any apache folder or modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

**Update**

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^option=(.+)&view=index$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://%1.mysite.com? [L]
```

Line by line:

1. You use the () in the first line to capture the value after option=
2. The url must start with index.php, the %1 refers to the captured value in line 1, the ? in the end makes sure the old
   query 
       string is not appended, the [L] stops executing the rest of the
       .htacces

Read more about it on 
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: You should probably include a link to the mod_rewrite docs while you're at it.